# Would 10 metres of liquid air be as effective against cosmic radiation as Earth's atmosphere?

Tags: radiation, atmospheric-science

Assuming ballpark figures which give a depth of 10m if the Earth's atmosphere was liquefied, would that be as effective a protection against ionizing radiation from space as the gaseous atmosphere is?

Comment: Do the calculation, at least!  What's the total molecule count for the atmosphere as opposed to "liquid air,"  which doesn't exist since different elements liquify at different temperatures?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It may not be as simple as that. It's a question of whether total mass is the key factor and whether density plays a part. Also, "liquid air" does exist since it can be bought. Presumably you are referring to trace amounts of CO2 (which freezes) and helium (which doesn't). Not really relevant to the spirit of the question

Comment: Ummm... total mass and density are rather closely linked.  Either a photon (or Fe nucleus) hits an air molecule or it doesn't.  The stats don't change based on the distance between the air molecules, just the number thereof.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Decay products would change depending on distance traveled, for example.

Comment: @DirkBruere: Nothing stops you from running a few GEANT simulations. I am going to be quite interested in the results.

Comment: @CuriousOne Lack of time and actually having an R&D job stops me. Finding the answer to my question is not high on my list of life's priorities. Also, GIGO - it all depends on assumptions made and there may be effects of which I am not aware that would affect the real answer

Comment: No offense, but what you are really saying here is that you don't mind if other people are running the GEANT jobs for you and then you can accuse them of doing a GIGO on you. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne I was just interested in the factors that may give different results between the two cases. No need to run simulations.

Comment: Maybe we should do an experiment, then. We certainly have the equipment all the way up to 7TeV. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For many—but not all—shielding processes the parameters of interest are proportional to the areal density, 
$$ \text{Range} \propto \frac{\text{areal density}}{\text{mass density}} = \frac{\sigma}{\rho} \,,$$
so a first expectation would be that the same areal density of material (of roughly the same composition) will have the same effect. I don't have the density of liquid air on hand, but if it is near that of water then your 10 meters is about the same areal density.

The first exception that comes to mind is cosmic muons: their range in the atmosphere is controlled largely by their lifetime and a non-trivial number decay before reaching sea level (this is the biggest component of the altitude dependence of the cosmic background dose). Your liquid air buffer will be no help there.

In the same vein there may be an extra component from the K-long products of primary and secondary interactions. Their $10^{-8}\,\mathrm{s}$ lifetime is not an issue with kilometers of atmosphere above you, but could be with only 10 meters of shielding. That's probably it for neutral survivers: the strange neutral baryons have rather shorter lifetimes (a $\Lambda^0$ lasts on average $3 \times 10^{-10}\,\mathrm{s}$ or about 10 centimeters times the Lorentz factor; few will have $\gamma > 100$).

A second issue where length rather than matter comes into play is with the consequences of neutron spallation. Once thermalized (which is areal density dependent) the neutrons spread out on a random walk with step size also inversely dependent on the areal density. But the time they spend walking depends on the neutron's lifetime, so the number of steps is larger for denser materials leading to a range falling slower than inversely in density
$$ \text{Range} \propto \sqrt{\frac{\tau}{v_\text{thermal}\, \rho}} \,.$$
So a larger fraction of spallation neutrons make it into your inhabited volume.